# How to use variable between functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a problem of using variables between functions. As you can see down below User.username is available and good at the sign up page, but when you go to the login page I told it to first alert the value of User.username, and it alerts undefined? I'm confused here. I'm pretty sure I'm missing a concept here. Anyways Thank you so much!:

Here is a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/qB3Gkeq5ji1YQyy0kpGH

Here is my *script.js*:

```
app.controller("AuthCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth","$rootScope", 
  function($scope, Auth, $rootScope) {
var User = {}

      $scope.createUser = function(username, email, password) {
        $rootScope.usernames = username
        User.username = username
        $scope.message = null;
        $scope.error = null;
    var ref2 = new Firebase("https://uniquecoders.firebaseio.com/");
  ref2.createUser({
    email: $scope.email,
    password: $scope.password
  }, function(error, userData) {
    if (error) {
      switch (error.code) {
        case "EMAIL_TAKEN":
          alert("The new user account cannot be created because the email is already in use. Try to login");
          break;
        case "INVALID_EMAIL":
          alert("The specified email is not a valid email.");
          break;
        case "INVALID_PASSWORD":
          alert("The Specified Passowrd Is not valid.")
          break;
        default:
          alert("Error creating user:", error);
      }
    } else {
      alert("Successfully created user account with username" + User.username);

      window.location.hash = "/User"
    }
  });


      };

       $scope.logIn = function(){
         alert(User.username)
       $rootScope.usernames = User.username
        $scope.message = null;
        $scope.error = null;
        var ref2 = new Firebase("https://uniquecoders.firebaseio.com/");
        ref2.authWithPassword({
          "email" : $scope.logInemail,
          "password" : $scope.logInemailpassword

        }, function(error, userData){

          if(error){
            alert("Login Failed Because : " + error)
          }
          else{
            alert("Logged In!")
            window.location.hash = "/User"
          }

        })

      }

  /*  $scope.removeUser = function() {
      $scope.message = null;
      $scope.error = null;

      Auth.$removeUser({
        email: $scope.email,
        password: $scope.password
      }).then(function() {
        $scope.message = "User removed";
      }).catch(function(error) {
        $scope.error = error;
      });
    };*/
  }
]);
```

Comment: This is why cookies exist.  Read about them

Comment: @Hogan i dont understand cookies. I dont want to go to another topic. Im asking if somone knows a concept?

Comment: Cookies are the concept.  Cookies are how you save data between pages.  That is what you are asking about right?

Comment: Wait im even more confused now @Hogan

Comment: @rishabhdev what are you talking about -- he made a plnker

Comment: @rishabhdev fiddle cant handle 9 files. I have 9 files in total as you see in plunker

Comment: ok I will try to explain -- but it is probably a lost cause.

Comment: As soon as you change the page by setting `window.location` or when the user clicks on a link that changes pages, then the entire Javascript environment (including all variables) is destroyed and replaced with a new one.  No JS variables survive from one page to the next.  Cookies and Local Storage are the two client-side places you can store stuff that you can then retrieve from a future page.

Comment: How do i store variables from cookies @jfriend00

Comment: I'd suggest you do some of your own research on cookies (Local Storage might actually be easier) and then post back when you have a more specific question.  Tons has already been written on this topic which doesn't need to be repeated here and doesn't fit in a comment either.

Comment: FYI, there are simple cookie functions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038929/displaying-cookies-on-a-website-using-javascript/28039037#28039037 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926119/cookie-to-show-a-popup-every-30-days/12926206#12926206

Comment: Yea @jfriend00 but i cant implement them to my code..

Comment: This isn't really the best way to handle an angular application.  Angular is a Single Page Application framework, it is designed to run all the code for your app in a single page.  What you have here is multiple angular applications navigating between each other, not a single application.  You should consider using a router like `ngRoute` or a state provider like `uiRouter` to manage your content on a single page.

Comment: what you are trying to attempt here is flawed.  As I said in the previous comment, since you don't have a single angular app but multiple angular apps, you cannot share variables between them.  You should re-structure your application and unify your views into a single app, before trying to solve why you can't share the variables.

Comment: There must be a way. How come people do this with angular js... @Claies

Comment: people do this with angular when they have a ***single angular application***.  You do not have a single angular application with the structure you have.

Comment: In angular, you should only be using `window.location` if you are navigating to a new application or outside website.

Comment: Then how do i do it? Im confused HOW? @Claies

Comment: fix your application so that all the *views* share the same *page*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100317/discussion-between-claies-and-dsafds).

Comment: The same page? Man im about to just Quit @Claies. What is with angular fire. Why do they make it so complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When page reloads the entire javascript is re executed. So user object populated in registration process is no longer available in login function because page has reloaded on clicking on signup button.
So we need to store the user name in cookie so that we can access it any time. Even when its removed from javascript runtime it will be there in the browser cache.
Its risky to store passwords in cookies for security issues.

On successful registration save the username in cookie.
Some thing like this

```
document.cookie ="username =" +username + "; " +"email ="+ email;
```

In  login function get cookie values and check if email of user is same as entered

```
function getCookie(name ) {
   var pairs = document.cookie.split("; "),
   count = pairs.length, parts; 
   while ( count-- ) {
    parts = pairs[count].split("=");
    if ( parts[0] === name )
        return parts[1];
}
 return false;
}


var username=getCookie("username");
var email=getCookie("username");
if($scope.logInemail ==email)
  {
     alert(username);
  }
```

Comment: ReferenceError: getCookie is not defined
    at Scope.$scope.logIn (https://preview.c9users.io/amanuel2/fourm/script.js:76:24)

Comment: code updated with getCookie function!. You can have that in function global scope. It can be used anywhere for getting cookie value.

Comment: I told it to alert the var username and it said it was false. Help please. Code is in script.js

Comment: alert("Successfully created user account with username" + User.username); You need to set cookies after this line. By adding the line document.cookie ="username =" +username + "; " +"email ="+ email;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100311/discussion-between-rishabh-dev-and-dsafds).

Comment: Sorry i was gone to somewhere ima check

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that a web application is a communication between the browser the the web server.  The browser and the server can be on different machines (even if they aren't when you are testing.)

There are two ways to make this work

While the browser and the server communicate some information is saved and passed back and forth on both ends -- this is called a cookie. This is the most common way to do save data between pages.  The browser requests a page.  When it get the reply from the server it contains a cookie.  The next time the browser requests a page it includes the cookie in it's request.  In this way the server knows the request is related to the prior request.

The server is smart enough to keep track of all "sessions" by different browsers.  It then saves session data about that communication -- when it gets the next request from the same browser it goes to the session data and retrieves information about that that browser and what it was doing.  (Often this is done with cookies.)

Comment: @Dsafds - as I said in my first comment "This is why cookies exist. Read about them".